# SPARQL query for finding the lowest class in a class hierarchy

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdfs

I want to write a SPARQL query for finding the lowest class in the hierarchy.
For example:

**Animal <---- Mammal <--- Dog <---- Dalmatian**

In rdf is like:

```
Animal rdf:type owl:Class;

Mammal rdf:type owl:Class;
       rdfs:subClassOf Animal;
Dog  rdf:type owl:Class;
       rdfs:subClassOf Mammal;
Dalmatian rdf:type owl:Class;
       rdfs:subClassOf Dog;
```

I want the query to return the Dalmatian.
How will I write such a SPARQL query?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: What I am thinking is to try to compare the classes by two, by running this query
ASK {
?var_subclass1 rdfs:subclassOf ?var_subclass2
}

and finally to get the class lowest in the hierarchy

Comment: well, I would reformulate your problem: you are looking for all classes that do not have any subclass (except `owl:Nothing`). All classes: `select ?cls {?cls a owl:Class}` - now you just have to add the filter. `select ?cls {?cls a owl:Class filter not exists {?sub rdfs:subClassOf ?cls filter(?sub != owl:Nothing)} }`

Comment: Unfortunately, for example, Mammal might have subclass since a query that I run returns those 4 classes in the description,  and then I want to retrieve the lowest in the hierarchy. Thus I do not think that I could restrict that in this way.

Comment: Do you mean that given a generic class, you want to return its lowest subclasses? In this case for Mammal you want Dalmatian, but you could also have Spaniel and Greyhound if they were in the data.

Comment: for a given class `:cls` you can do `select distinct ?cls {?sub rdfs:subClassOf* :cls not exists {?other_sub rdfs:subClassOf ?sub filter(?sub != owl:Nothing)} }` - but, for lowest you'd need the length of the path - there are limitations in that regards with SPARQL, especially once you have cycles and/or multliple paths between the same node pair

Comment: My path is linear, so I ll not have for example Greyhound, only Dalmatian. So I need the lowest in the hierarchy. Of course the query that you sent, it would work if Dalmatian had not another subclass. But for some reason related to the functionality of my algorithm, I need to get the Dalmatian, given an input of a subclasses (e.g. Animal <---- Mammal <--- Dog <---- Dalmatian)
The only way that I can see is to  to compare the classes by two, by running this query ASK { ?var_subclass1 rdfs:subclassOf ?var_subclass2 } and finally to get the class lowest in the hierarchy

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking then. My query does only return Dalmatian when applied to your sample data. Moreover, it does only return the leafs in the class hierarchy. What exactly does not work with it?